# Ubuntu 13.10 can't drag a window up to another screen

Tags: unity, 13.10, compiz

I am having Ubuntu 13.04 and 13.10. I have no problem with 13.04

In 13.10 I found that, when I tried to drag my window up across my standard dual-screen setup, it gets *jammed/stopped* when it goes as high as the top menu bar and won't go higher into my other screen that's configured from *system-settings->displays* to be right *above the current one*.

In another word, My external monitor is positioned as *above* my internal laptop's screen, and I'm trying to drag my window *up* from my laptop screen into my external monitor screen. Dragging a window in reverse direction, e.g. *down* from external screen to my laptop screen is totaly fine.

I disabled maximizing at top screen edge (from CCSM) but still window won't drag up through the lower screen's top edge. I thought this might be related to some kind of snapping but I don't see any options for this in `compiz-config`.

could this be about unity's menu bar? Or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

I found your post when searching for a solution to the same problem, as I prefer my second monitor "stacked" over my laptop monitor. After fiddling around with it, I discovered that if you drag the window very quickly, it will work. If you drag it more casually, it will get stuck trying to snap/enlarge.

I've decided I like this behavior because it allows me to snap/enlarge on my lower monitor quite effortlessly, but I can still drag to the other when needed.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I tried it and it works for something but not everything, e.g. very large windows generally takes several tries, sometimes after 5-6 failed attempt to drag it 'up' I have to use Alt-Left-Mouse to drag window up - very uncool as it takes (1) move title-bar into 'top' screen, then (2) drag it up. ..

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but what I found out was that the window got jammed by the other - smaller window because the window was not allowed to exit the edges of the smaller screen.

making the window smaller, or bypassing the corner - allowed me to drag it to the other window.

It is counter-intuitive, since we're used to allow windows to go beyond the screen edges, and only the mouse is supposed to be confined by the edges.
I think this behavior is a bug.